# Fourier transforms on piecewise functions

Tags: solution-verification, fourier-transform

I would like to derive the Fourier transform of a function given by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2, & -1 < x < 1 \\ 
0, & \text{Elsewhere} 
\end{cases}$$

I derived it by defining the Fourier transform as

$$F(k) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(x) \exp(ikx) dx$$

I got

$$\frac{2a^2}{k}\sin(ka) + \frac{4a}{k^2}\sin(ka)-\frac{4}{k^3}\sin(ka)$$

Is that correct?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: to calculate the Fourier transform of the function in my question?

Comment: But didn't you do it already? $$F(k) = \frac{2a^{2}}{k} \sin(ka) + \dots$$

Comment: I'm asking if I did it right...